# How can I manage to put a button image into an image background Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, button

Good day everyone, can I ask how can I manage to put this button inside an image background

code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image



root = Tk()
root.title("Japanese Retro Hub")
root.geometry('2200x1000')

#Image
bg = Image.open("RetroHub_BG_Main.png")
resized = bg.resize((2200,1000), Image.ANTIALIAS)
bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
bglabel = Label(root, image=bg)
bglabel.pack(pady=20)

#text for my_command and Start exit button
text = Label(root, text= "Hello world")
text.pack(pady=30)




def my_command():
    text.config(text="You have clicked Me...")

def start_exit_button():
    click_btn = PhotoImage(file='start_button.png')
    img_label= Label(image=click_btn)
    button = Button(root, image=click_btn,command=my_command,borderwidth=0)
    button.pack(padx=50, pady=20)


    root.mainloop()


start_exit_button()
root.mainloop()
```

This is the image example that I am trying to portray
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VzbhNazEnfOCk0_QZOD_nWR5jsb-a8GB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can use `.place()` instead of `.pack()`: `button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='c')`.

Comment: thank you thank you so much sir for helping me fix this problem